# How to put a trigger in a stage step in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Before use stages, I had put the trigger inside the step:

```
- step: &deployment-prod
      name: Deploy
      trigger: manual
      script:
        - echo "production deployment script"
```

However, nowadays I was needed to use stages to deploy to multiple environments and I'm receiving the following error:

`A step within stage can't contain a manual trigger. Try defining a manual trigger on a stage.`

I also tried do like that, but with no success:

```
- stage:
     name: Deploy to Production
     deployment: Production
         steps:
            - step: 
                <<: *deployment-prod
                trigger: manual
```

Someone can help me?? plsssss

I want to use bitbucket pipeline stages with a trigger inside a step.

Comment: It is covered in the limitations https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/stage-options/#Limitations and laters they cover trigger usage for stage https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/stage-options/#Trigger

Comment: @Randommm your comment could be pretty much THE answer to this question if you want to repost it along with a code excerpt (remember no link-only answers and whatnot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is covered in their documentation about Stages https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/stage-options/#Limitations

- The maximum number of steps you can within a stage is:
- 10 steps for workspaces on the Free plan.
- 100 steps for workspaces on a Standard or Premium plan.
- Parallel stages are not supported.
- A stage can't include parallel steps.
- **A stage can't contain manually triggered steps, but you can configure a stage to be manually triggered.**
- A stage can't contain conditional steps, but you can configure a stage to be conditional.
- Disabling artifact downloads inside a stage is not supported.
- Steps can't override any property also set on a stage.
- Partially completed deployment stages can't be continued if another change was subsequently deployed to the same environment.

---

To use manual trigger on a stage, the also have that documented specifically https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/stage-options/#Trigger

Example on how to use triggers with stages

```
pipelines:
   default:
    - stage:
        name: Linting
        steps:
          - step:
              script:
              - sh ./run-linter.sh
    - stage:
        name: Build and test
        trigger: manual
        steps:
          - step:
              name: Build app
              script:
                - sh ./build-app.sh
          - step:
              name: Run unit tests
              script:
                - sh ./run-tests.sh
```